# Grammar tool that (really) works offline on Linux

Tags: linux, offline, language, grammar

I need a grammar language assistant. I am available to pay a licence, but I am looking for something that works offline on Linux. Currently I am using the free version of ProseLint , but it misses a lot of things, like words in singular form associated to verbs in plural form and clauses joined with the wrong words.

I tried to search via search engine and [alternativeto](https://alternativeto.net), but I had to go through a long list of shady tools that repeat dozen of times that they don't track the users, use the flag *Works Offline*, but then when you look how you can install and use them you see that all of them are not what they claim. LanguageTool say that it works like a plugin for LibreOffice, but then you have to configure an API in LibreOffice plugins with a permanent server connection. Grammarly and Trinka AI on linux are available only as browser plugins. Many others are online.

There are a lot of other tools like StyleWriter or Hemingway Editor that work only on Windows.

I am looking for something like ProseLint where I prepare a text (.txt) file that might contain 10/15 thousands words, I execute it and then I check the report. 
If it is more powerful than ProseLint as I wrote above I am willing to pay for the licence.